# AbstractTableModel won't update JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, abstracttablemodel

i'm trying to make my JTable show changes made to my TableModel extending AbstractTableModel. I made a Heap to insert all the documents and then I apply a heapSort on my heap array, so this ordered array should be my TableModel data. It looks like this:

```
public class ModeloTabla extends AbstractTableModel {

    private Heap heap;
    private Nodo[] datos;

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return heap.getNumNodos();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if ( !heap.empty() ) {
            datos = heap.heapSort();
        }
        Documento doc = datos[rowIndex].getDocumento();
        switch ( columnIndex ) {
            case 0:
                return doc.getNombre();
            case 1:
                return doc.getHojas();
            case 2:
                return doc.getPrioridad();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `getValueAt` method when I call `heap.heapSort()` the heap internal array is destroyed and it returns a `Nodo[]` with the ordered nodes. So when `datos` has an ordered array with nodes, my JTable won't show the data. Now, if I don't execute the `heap.heapSort()` and instead just call for the unordered array from the heap, my JTable shows everything.

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        datos = heap.getDatos();
        Documento doc = datos[rowIndex].getDocumento();
        ... //This works but datos is unordered
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing the Heap unordered array with the ordered one inside `heapSort()` and returning it using `getDatos()` but then the JTable again won't show up, also I've checked for the returning array from `heapSort()` and it's working well, the data is the same as the one from `getDatos()` but ordered. Any help with this would be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the getValueAt() method you are retrieving the data from the datos object.

> Documento doc = datos[rowIndex].getDocumento();

So the row count should be based on the number of rows in the datos object.

```
public int getRowCount() {
        //return heap.getNumNodos();
        return datos.length;
    }
```

The getValueAt() method should NOT be sorting the data. The data in the model should already be sorted. Either sort it externally or sort it when you create the model. That is the getValueAt() method should not be changing the structure of the data. Also every time you change the data you would need to resort.

Comment: Thanks, the Nodo[] datos object isn't created with the model, I use it to store the ordered array from the `heapSort()`, so I can't use the `datos.length` because is not created yet at that point. Also, I just modified the getValueAt() method to show: `datos = heap.getDatos();` and this is returning an already sorted array but still it doesn't show up. It's weird that the JTable shows the model while using the heap array directly and not when it's ordered.

Comment: `so I can't use the datos.length because is not created yet at that point.` That is my point! It should be created and contain valid data when the class is constructed. The getValueAt() method only does one thing, that is get the value from the data structure. It does NOT sort the data structure first.

Comment: `It's weird that the JTable shows the model while using the heap array directly and not when it's ordered` - maybe your heap sort doesn't do what you expect. Why do you even have a Heap class? Your TableModel should NOT contain two data structure to hold the data. Just use the Collections API to do the sorting for you. Or use the sorting feature of JTable.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, right now I'm trying to figure out how to update my datos each time I insert a new document, because also my table model has some methods to insert into the heap, and those are called from a controller class. And yeah, this is for an assignment so I have to use the Heap to sort everything and it depends on an option to sort it with a MinHeap or a MaxHeap, using a different key on the document. About the heap sort thing, I've checked entry by entry and it's returning an array of nodes with the same nodes but ordered.

Comment: `I'm trying to figure out how to update my datos each time I insert a new document, because also my table model has some methods to insert into the heap` - when you invoke the method in the TableModel you update the heap, then sort the heap, then you invoke the fireTableDataChanged(...) method so the table can repaint itself with all the objects in the proper sorted order.

Comment: Thank you so much! This finally made it. I didn't have to call fireTableDataChanged(), just insert the document into the heap, then send the sorted heap to datos and remove the datos = getDatos() from getValueAt(). Thank you!

Comment: @SergioGarcía, You need to invoke the fireTableDataChanged() method in case the inserted item cause the display order of the rows to change. Basically this method will tell the table to repaint itself.